# jQuery - $(document).ready working only after refresh on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#aside_left").css({'height':($("#central").outerHeight()+'px')});
    $("#aside_right").css({'height':($("#central").outerHeight()+'px')});
});
```

which should make divs with ids "aside_left" and "aside_right" have the same height as the div with id "central".

It works great in Chrome. 
In Firefox it doesn't follow the exact height of the "central", but maybe some 95%. This happens on first (uncached) load of the page from the server and every time I press CTRL+F5 (bypass the cache reload). After the second refresh on F5, it follows the 100% of the "central" div, as it should.

Anyone got any idea why?
Thanks

Comment: Can we have your html markup ?

Comment: can you try to put that code inside `$(window).on('load', function() { ... })` to see if it works any better

Comment: provide your html too

Comment: Putting $(window).on('load', function() { ... }) as Jaromanda X suggested solved the issue. It seems it was a matter of executing the script after the whole page. Sounds simple now.. Thanks